# Decorator pattern — how do I track decorators?

Tags: c#, decorator

I want to track all the decorators in a sorted set, how can I do that?

My thought is to have a collection that I just add decorators to during the wrapping process in the constructor, however my current implementation keeps returning a collection with a single item in it. Can someone help me fix this?

Service is a component; Labor and Equipment are Decorators.

```
public abstract class Service : IComparable<Service>
{
    public abstract decimal JobCost { get; }
    public virtual SortedSet<Service> Description { get; } = new SortedSet<Service>();
    public void AddToStack() => Description.Add(this);

    public int CompareTo(Service other)
    {
        // if both are labor services, then 
        if ((this is Labor) && (other is Labor))
        {
            return (this as Labor).Time.CheckIn.CompareTo((other as Labor).Time.CheckIn);
        }

        if (other is Equipment)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        return -2;
    }
}

public abstract class ServiceDecorator : Service
{
    public abstract override SortedSet<Service> Description { get; }
}


public class Labor : ServiceDecorator
{
    private Service service;
    private LaborRatesDual laborRates;
    private LaborTime laborTime;

    public Labor(Service service, LaborTime laborTime, LaborRatesDual laborRates)
    {
        this.service = service;
        this.laborTime = laborTime;
        this.laborRates = laborRates;

        this.service.AddToStack();
    }

    public int WorkOrderNo { get; set; }
    public string PO { get; set; }
    public override SortedSet<Service> Description => new SortedSet<Service>(service.Description);

    public int TechCount { get; set; } = 1;
    public LaborTime Time
    {
        get { return laborTime; }
        set { laborTime = value; }
    }
    public LaborRatesDual Rates
    {
        get { return laborRates; }
        set { laborRates = value; }
    }

    // labor time to complete the service (labor time x tech count)
    public TimeSpan Duration => TimeSpan.FromTicks(Time.Duration.Ticks * TechCount);

    // get the cost for this particular labor service
    public decimal Cost
    {
    ...
    }

    // returns complete job cost, including the wrapped object
    public override decimal JobCost => service.JobCost + Cost;

    // helps identify is the service should be billed at continuous rate, or if the time
    // should be billable using the dual-rate system
    public bool IsContinuation { get; set; } = false;

}


public class Equipment : ServiceDecorator
{
    Service service;
    EquipmentTime time;
    EquipmentRate rate;

    public Equipment(Service service, EquipmentTime equipmentTime, EquipmentRate equipmentRate)
    {
        this.service = service;
        this.time = equipmentTime;
        this.rate = equipmentRate;

        this.service.AddToStack();
    }

    public EquipmentTime Time
    {
        get { return time; }
        set { time = value; }
    }
    public int UnitCount { get; set; } = 1;
    public decimal Rate
    {
        get { return rate.Rate; }
        set { rate.Rate = value; }
    }
    public bool UseCalendarDayCount { get; set; } = false;

    // units x days
    public int FullCount
    {
     ...
    }

    public override SortedSet<Service> Description => new SortedSet<Service>(service.Description);

    public decimal Cost => FullCount * Rate;

    public override decimal JobCost => service.JobCost + Cost;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change SortedSet to static. And don't create new one in new decorators. Any of your decorator have his own SortedSet so they dont share your basic instance.